# Udev rule to rename USB device does not seem to work

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, udev

On a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 on aarch64, I have a USB ZWave device that I want to expose at a specific name, so I wrote a simple `udev` rule to do so, but it doesn't seem to work.

The vendor:product id is `0658:0200`

My rule is

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", NAME="ttyZWAVE0"
```

Yet the device continues to show up as `ttyACM0`.

If I use the following rule, which has the same match criteria, to create a symbolic link instead, the symbolic link does show up correctly:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="ttyZWAVE0"
```

Here was my `udevadm --name=/dev/ttyACM0 --attribute-walk` output before creating the rule:

```
  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1':
    KERNELS=="1-1.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.1"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="12"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{devspec}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="02"
```

Why does the rule to straight-up rename it not work, either with a `udev trigger` or a full system restart, yet the rule to add a symlink *does* work? Am I missing something simple?

I see nothing useful at all in journalctl (literally nothing even mentioning it, no errors, no nothing).

Edit to add:

This also seems to fail in the same way on my laptop, running Ubuntu 20.04 on amd64, with the exact same results (obviously with different parent device paths).

`udevadm test /sys/path/to/device` is giving no obvious answers, either, as to why it doesn't do what I expect. It does show it reading my rules and there are no errors...

Comment: I just tried writing the rule as `KERNELS=="1-3", NAME="ttyZWAVE0", SYMLINK+="ttyZWAVE1"` and what do I get?  Still ttyACM0 and also the symlink for ttyZWAVE1. Why is it refusing to rename the device? It obviously is matching and taking action... But then it is ignoring the part I actually care about.

Comment: Continuing to look into it, I thought, ok...maybe one of the default rules was taking precedence. So I did a `grep ACM /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/*` and I can't find one that seems like it should be matching this device more specifically than my rule. Are udev rules a last-match-wins sort of thing, or does the most specific match win? Because my rules runs first, before any other rule.

Comment: Follow-up to my latest comment... I renamed my rule so it would run last, and `udevadm test` gave a new bit of useful output... `ttyACM0: /etc/udev/rules.d/zzz.rules:1 Kernel device nodes cannot be renamed, ignoring NAME="ttyZWAVE0"; please fix it.`  So is this just not something I'm allowed to do at all, or is there a way around this? I found this, but `man udev` on my system has no such text: https://askubuntu.com/questions/546100/why-cant-my-udev-rules-rename-kernel-device-nodes-after-upgrading-from-12-04-to

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not allowed, according to udev documentation. As shown in a couple of other questions I found since I posted this one, it's mentioned in the man pages. I did not find this caveat until I named my rule in a way which would make it run last, triggering an error from `udevadm test` that pointed me in the right direction.

It is documented at the official site and in udev.7.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html

Comment: Older versions of `udev` used to allow it, but it turned out to be open to abuse, and so modern versions are more strict. (The usual story: someone was being naughty, and that's why we all cannot have some nice things...)